# Wordpress: If user role is 'travel agent' redirect to 'my-account'

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom role called "Travel Agent" using `add_role( 'travel_agent', 'Travel Agent', array( 'book_hotel' ) );` at my themes functions.php

However, I don't want this user to have access to the dashboard so I want to redirect him to "my-account" after log in.

I am using this code at wp-login.php/functions.php without any luck:

```
function redirect_agents() {
  if ( current_user_can('book_hotel') ){
      return '/my-account';
  }
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_agents');
```

How ever, I don't get redirected.. But if I use such code without the If at functions.php as this:

```
 function redirect_agents() {
          return '/my-account';
    }

add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_agents');
```

It works but then all users get redirected to my account. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes Hotels are custom post, `http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap` you can register your own capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use WordPress global $current_user.

```
if(in_array('travel_agent', $current_user->roles)) {
  return '/my-account';
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that it means they'll never be able to look at any other page while they're logged in.

Comment: Well I'd guess this would be contained in a function and called conditionally elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that would make sense!

Answer (score 0):

The `login_redirect` filter accepts three parameters: `redirect_to` (contains current redirect value), `request` (the URL the user is coming from) and `user` (the user that has logged in as a WP_User object).

You can use the `user` parameter inside your function to determine whether to redirect or not:

```
add_filter( "login_redirect", "custom_login_redirect", 10, 3 );

function custom_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user )
{
    if ( in_array( "role_name", $user -> roles ) )
    {
        return "/hello-world";
    }

    // Remember to return something just in case,
    // as filters can possibly block execution if
    // they do not return anything.
    else
    {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
```

You might also want to verify that the `$user` is a proper WP_User object, to ensure correct execution.

You can try using the $current_user global variable, but it may or may not be defined when `login_redirect` is executed.

[More information is available at the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect).